# Opacity slider for a fabric object

Tags: javascript, canvas, opacity, fabricjs

I have a canvas and it includes fabric objects.I want to do opacity slider for text area's backround "textbackroundColor" in canvas.How can I do slide and change functions?

```
$("#backgroundOpacity").slider( {
     min: 10,
     max: 50,
     value: 30,
     slide: text_bgColor_slider_moved,
     change: text_bgColor_slider_changed

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

first get active object of canvas

```
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
```

and then

```
$("#backgroundOpacity").slider( {
       max : 100,
       value : activeObject.opacity * 100,
       slide: function (event, ui) {
           activeObject.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
           canvas.renderAll();
       },
       stop : function (event, ui) {
           canvas.renderAll();
       }
});
```

Comment: How can I active object? I got an error "not defined" when I wrote like this "var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();"

Comment: click any of the object text picture or other and if border appears object is active

Answer (score 0):

Another way, via a range input coupled with $(document).on

```
$(document).on("change", "#alpha", function () {
transval = $(this).val();
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
obj.set({
opacity: transval
});
canvas.renderAll();
});
```