# Incorporating Opacity Slider for Selected Object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to incorporate an opacity slider so that any selected objects are set to change based on the slider's position (100 being completely visible). I'm using `fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js` and jQuery 3.3.1. What am I doing wrong here? [I am basically trying to incorporate the Opacity slider on fabricjs.com](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink).

**I'm getting this error:**
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined"

**What I have:**
https://codepen.io/s-harper/pen/QxeMXL

**Answers I've tried incorporating:** [Opacity slider for a fabric object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813552/opacity-slider-for-a-fabric-object)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

// select, draw
$("#select").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
});
$("#draw").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
});

var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();

$("#alpha").slider( {
       max : 100,
       value : activeObject.opacity * 100,
       slide: function (event, ui) {
           activeObject.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
           canvas.renderAll();
       },
       stop : function (event, ui) {
           canvas.renderAll();
       }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

fieldset {
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<br>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>
<button id="select">Select</button>
<br>
<br>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Controls</legend>
  <label for="alpha">Opactity</label>
  <input type="range" id="alpha" name="alpha" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1" />
</fieldset>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the example, I get an error on `activeObject.opacity`, because `activeObject` is undefined. Is this the same error you get? Your question doesn’t say, so I’m not sure whether this is the error you’re trying to fix or whether something has been lost in translation.

Comment: @Aankhen hi, I'm getting too (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined). Isn't `activeObject` defined? I'm not getting an error for `activeObject` when I run it.

Comment: From what I can tell, `getActiveObject` will only return an object if there is one, which there isn’t when the canvas is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get activeobject using events like `selection:created, selection:updated` and use jquery ui for jquery slider.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

// select, draw
$("#select").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
});
$("#draw").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
});
var activeObject = null;
canvas.on('selection:created', function(options) {
  activeObject = options.target;
  $("#alpha").slider("option", "value", activeObject.opacity);
});
canvas.on('selection:updated', function(options) {
  activeObject = options.target;
  $("#alpha").slider("option", "value", activeObject.opacity);
});
canvas.on('selection:cleared', function(options) {
  activeObject = null;
});
$("#alpha").slider({
  max: 1,
  min: 0,
  step: 0.1,
  value: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    activeObject && (activeObject.opacity = ui.value)
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

fieldset {
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<br>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>
<button id="select">Select</button>
<br>
<br>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Controls</legend>
  <label for="alpha">Opactity</label>
  <div id="alpha" name="alpha"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hey @Durga I made a mistake, I'm actually using fabricjs v 1.7.22. I've been reading over the documentation and have tried changing the activeObject but must be missing something. How would I change this to work with 1.7.22? http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/srm25f9d/

Comment: I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250832/opacity-slider-for-objects