# Opacity Slider for Objects

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to incorporate an opacity slider so that any selected objects are set to change based on the slider's position (100 being completely visible). I'm using Fabric.js version 1.7.22 and jQuery 3.3.1.

I originally asked this and got a working solution (thank you @Durga) but realized I was using the wrong Fabric.js version. I've looked over the docs but am stuck. What am I doing wrong here?

**What I have:**
http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/srm25f9d/

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

// select, draw
$("#select").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
});
$("#draw").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
});
var activeObject = null;
canvas.on('selection:created', function(options) {
  activeObject = options.target;
  $("#alpha").slider("option", "value", activeObject.opacity);
});
canvas.on('selection:updated', function(options) {
  activeObject = options.target;
  $("#alpha").slider("option", "value", activeObject.opacity);
});
canvas.on('selection:cleared', function(options) {
  activeObject = null;
});
$("#alpha").slider({
  max: 1,
  min: 0,
  step: 0.1,
  value: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    activeObject && (activeObject.opacity = ui.value)
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

fieldset {
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<br>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>
<button id="select">Select</button>
<br>
<br>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Controls</legend>
  <label for="alpha">Opactity</label>
  <div id="alpha" name="alpha"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any problem, if you upgrade fabricjs to v2?

Comment: Hi Durga, yes it doesn't operate as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need to update one object at the time then you can you FabriJs function getActiveObject() to update opacity:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

// select, draw
$("#select").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
});
$("#draw").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
});

$("#alpha").slider({
  max: 1,
  min: 0,
  step: 0.1,
  value: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    if (canvas.getActiveObject()){
        canvas.getActiveObject().setOpacity(ui.value);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});
```

If you will need to play with multiple objects then you'll need to loop and change opacity for each object separately.

Answer (score 1):

Use `object:selected` event to get the selected object and on `selection:cleared` 
remove active object.

For v2 [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228960/3551786).

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

// select, draw
$("#select").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
});
$("#draw").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
});

var activeObject = null;

canvas.on('object:selected', function(options) {
  activeObject = options.target;
  $("#alpha").slider("option", "value", activeObject.opacity);
});
canvas.on('selection:cleared', function(options) {
  activeObject = null;
  $("#alpha").slider("option", "value", 1);
});

$("#alpha").slider({
  max: 1,
  min: 0,
  step: 0.1,
  value: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    activeObject && (activeObject.opacity = ui.value)
    canvas.renderAll();
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

fieldset {
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<br>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>
<button id="select">Select</button>
<br>
<br>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Controls</legend>
  <label for="alpha">Opactity</label>
  <div id="alpha" name="alpha"></div>
</fieldset>
```